# Verificar Nuevos pedidos (jquery - PHP - MYSL)

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

tengo un sistema para restaurante en el cual existe un administrador (admin.php) y varios meceros (mozo.php) ambos usando la misma base de datos, cuando el administrador tiene el panel abierto y el mecero genere un nuevo pedido deseo que su pagina se actualize `(location.reload())` para poder mostrar los nuevos pedidos actualizados.

Esto uso yo:

```
function socket(data = null,n=null) {
    setInterval(function () {
      if ($('#notif_pedidos').is(':hidden')){
        $.ajax({
            url: "socket.php", type: 'GET', data: data, dataType: 'HTML',
            success: function (resp) {
if (parseInt(n) < parseInt(resp)){

if($("#toggle-autoreload").prop('checked')) {

f5();

}else{
$('#notif_pedidos').slideDown();
audio.play();

}
}
                }            
        });
        }
    }, 17000);
}
```

y lo llamo asi:

```
socket("123&modo_pedidos=1","5");
```

el primer parametro es el id de la sucursal y el modo pedido (1,2,3); el segundo parametro son los pedidos actuales

cosa que en socket.php hago una consulta mysql a mi base de datos donde retorno cuantos pedidos existen actualmente y jquery recibe este numero y lo compara con los pedidos actuales y si ahy mas pedidos que los actuales recarga la web, pero esta consulta la hace cada x segundos, y pienso que esto esta saturando mi servidor porque llega un punto en el que la pagina deja de funcionar y "cae", ustedes podrian proponerme una mejor opcion? sin considerar firebase ya que el sistema ya esta armado asi y tengo que entregarlo pronto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la librería de [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) para poder saber exactamente cuando un mesero realice un nuevo pedido, ya con socket puedes realizar la consulta cuando sea necesario en cambio con el setInterval se realiza cada x tiempo y puede saturar al servidor por peticiones de otras funciones.